# retrieving data from Json with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to use Jquery to get the attributes of a Json variable. I made an ajax request with:

```
 $.ajax({ 
       url: 'myURL/' + id + '/' + date, 
       dataType: 'json', 
 }).done(function (data) {}
```

I put the url in the browser,and the returned data is like:

```
{"pico":0,"valle":1,"administrativas":"0"}
```

So, inside de *done function* how I get the value of *pico* variable for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it simple using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myURL/' + id + '/' + date, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.pico);
    }
});
```

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova Enjoy the day! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: 'myURL/' + id + '/' + date, 
   dataType: 'json', 
}).done(function (data) {
 console.log(data.pico);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By accessing the property in the data response:

```
var data = {"pico":0,"valle":1,"administrativas":"0"};
console.log(data.pico);
```